# Возможно ли поместить Activity в Fragment

Tags: android, android-studio, android-fragment, activity

Возможно ли поместить Activity в Fragment?
Если да, то как?

Comment: Зачем? И что значит `поместить`?

Comment: Нет... И ОМГ ЗАЧЕМ???

Comment: Хмм... интересный вопрос...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

конечно нет. Активити это компонента занимающая весь экран. К тому же на экране активной может находится только одна активити. ( В состоянии OnResume() ). Для решения вашего желания есть 2 варианта:

1 - поместить другой фрагмент в ваш (так все обычно и делают)

2 - стартовать новую активити из вашего фрагмента. Но новая активити по сути будет новым "экраном"